# how to uncheck all cells on tableview in ios

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a tableview, where when the user selects the cell it will set the `accessorytype` to `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`.

Now when I navigate to the previous screen, then go forward to this tableview, my cells remains checked.

Is there a way to uncheck all of them? I guess basically set all of them to `UITableViewCellAccessoryNone`.

I tried using `reloadData`, when the view appear, but that doesn't seem to trigger the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (this is where my logic is to set the `accessorytype` of the cells)

Comment: Can you post your cellForRowAtIndexPath code?

Comment: Try using `- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation` if you want to force the complete reload. But this is not the right way. You should make the changes in your `MODEL` then update your `VIEW`. If your `MODEL` and your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` are correct - then the simple `reloadData` will do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the accessorytype in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` instead of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` so that it is updated whenever it is displayed (and not just when created).

Answer (score 3):

I think this may do what you want. I assume you want to uncheck all the cells as part of responding to tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: but you could insert this code anywhere:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
    didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Uncheck any visible, checked cells.
    NSArray *visibleCells = [tableView visibleCells];
    for (UITableViewCell *cell in visibleCells) {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    }

    // Now do whatever else you want in response to a row being selected.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a tableview method called clearsselectiononviewwillappear that you might have accidentally overwritten.  The default behavior should be YES.  Check out Apple's [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
 on UITab

Comment: i think that is to clear the selection, meaning when you select a cell it is highlighted. I think its to clear the highlighted row. cuz i didnt override this at all